# StructureMap dynamic set properties per HttpRequest

Tags: structuremap

StructureMap Configuration

Is there a way in SM to dynamically inject property value only for the duration of a request then set the those property back to default after the request is completed?

I'm specifically referring in the HttpRequest context.

I have a IDBAccessor interface and a DBAccessor concrete implementation.

IDBAccessor has a public property for connection string.

I want to set the connectionstring dynamically for each HttpRequest depending on some parameter that is passed in.

Is there an easy to accomplish this?

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a class that encapsulates the logic to determine the connection string for each request. I'll call it `ConnectionStringSource`. You could then configure StructureMap like this:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.For<IDBAccessor>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
        .Use(ctx =>
        {
            var connectionString = ctx.GetInstance<ConnectionStringSource>().GetConnectionString();
            var dbAccessor = new DBAccessor {ConnectionString = connectionString};
            return dbAccessor;
        });
});

public class ConnectionStringSource
{
    public string GetConnectionString()
    {
        // determine the connection string somehow
        return "connection string";
    }
}
```

The `HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped` call will make sure you get a new instance of `DBAccessor` for each HTTP request. And by using the `Func<>` overload of `Use()`, you can execute the code to determine and set the connection string during each request.

*Note: You might want to just make the connection string a constructor parameter of DBAccessor instead of making it a property on the interface.*